# Laurent series expansion for powers of n?

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem, laurent-series

I wish to expand the function:

$$\dfrac{e^z}{z^n-c^n}$$

about the point $z_0=c$, where c is a constant greater than 0 and n is greater than 2.

So I have that $e^{z-c}$ expands to $1+(z-c)+\frac{1}{2!}(z-c)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(z-c)^3+...$, but I am unsure how to incorporate the denominator. A difference of powers like that could be found using the binomial theorem, but I'm not sure how to generalize this. I have been messing around with it, and I've generalized it to the following:

$$\dfrac{x^n-y^n}{x-n}=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+x^{n-3}y^{2}+...+x^{n-k-1}y^{k}+...+y^{n-1}$$

How can I clean this up? Is this the right method? I need the calculate the integral using the residue theorem, so I need to be able to pull the residue out of this. Thanks!

Comment: Is [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent+series+of+e%5Ez%2F%28z%5En-c%5En%29+at+z%3Dc) what you're looking for?

Comment: I suppose that would be the end result! I am trying to understand how to get there. @Demosthene

Comment: For the residue, you don't need the full Laurent expansion. Here, the denominator has a simple zero, and that makes things quite easy: the residue of $\frac{f}{g}$ at a simple zero $z_0$ of $g$ is $\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$.

Comment: Does this produce the following? $$\frac{e^c}{-n(c^{n-1})}$$ That doesn't agree with the WolframAlpha result, but I do recognize the theory you're speaking of. Thanks for the help, by the way! @DanielFischer

Comment: No, the minus sign is wrong, the residue is $$\frac{e^c}{nc^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, this is really basic, but where does the minus sign go? @DanielFischer

Comment: There is no minus sign. You need to take the derivative of $z^n-c^n$ at $z=c$, which is simply $nc^{n-1}$.

Comment: The question is, where should it come from? Here we have $f(z) = e^z$ and $g(z) = z^n - c^n$, so $g'(z) = n z^{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I was taking the derivative with respect to the wrong variable. This clears it up. Thank you! @DanielFischer